# Python3 pipe I/O on np.ndarray with raw binary data failed

Tags: python, numpy, file-io, pipe

I have a binary raw data file `in.dat` storing 4 int32 values.

```
$ xxd in.dat 
00000000: 0100 0000 0200 0000 0300 0000 0400 0000  ................
```

I want to read them into `np.ndarray`, multiply by 2, then write them out to stdout with the same raw binary format as `in.dat`. The expected output is like,

```
$ xxd out.dat 
00000000: 0200 0000 0400 0000 0600 0000 0800 0000  ................
```

The code is like this,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = np.fromfile(sys.stdin, dtype='int32')
    y *= 2
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(y.astype('int32').tobytes())
    exit(0)
```

I find it works as expected with `<`,

```
$ python3 test.py <in.dat >out.dat
```

But it does not work with a pipe `|`. Here comes the error message.

```
$ cat in.dat | python3 test.py >out.dat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 7, in <module>
    y = np.fromfile(sys.stdin, dtype='int32')
OSError: obtaining file position failed
```

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when redirecting a file in, stdin is seekable (because it isn't a TTY or pipe, for example, it's just a file that's been given FD 1). Try invoking the following script with `cat foo.txt | python3 test.py` vs `python3 test.py <foo.txt` (assuming foo.txt contains some text):

```
import sys

sys.stdin.seek(1)
print(sys.stdin.read())
```

The former will error with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    sys.stdin.seek(1)
io.UnsupportedOperation: underlying stream is not seekable
```

That said, numpy is way overkill for what you're trying to do here. You can easily achieve this with a few lines and `struct`:

```
import struct
import sys

FORMAT = '@i'


def main():
    try:
        while True:
            num = struct.unpack(FORMAT, sys.stdin.buffer.read(struct.calcsize(FORMAT)))
            sys.stdout.buffer.write(struct.pack(FORMAT, num * 2))
    except EOFError:
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Edit:** there's also no need for `sys.exit(0)`. This is the default.

Comment: You're right, but it would still be interesting why `numpy.fromfile` needs a seekable file handle. I would expect it to work with any file.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `np.frombuffer`, it should work both ways:

pipebytes.py

```
import numpy as np
import sys
print(np.frombuffer(sys.stdin.buffer.read(), dtype=np.int32))
```

Now,

```
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ xxd testdata.dat
00000000: 0100 0000 0200 0000 0300 0000            ............
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ python pipebytes.py < testdata.dat
[1 2 3]
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$ cat testdata.dat | python pipebytes.py
[1 2 3]
Juans-MacBook-Pro:temp juan$
```

Although, I suspect this will make a copy of the data.

Comment: @BaileyParker yes, I suspected that :)